# How do I decode/unescape HTML entities in Erlang?

Tags: html, xml, erlang

I'm making a REST call and receiving this XML back:

```
<replacement><![CDATA[this is &amp; ampersand]]></replacement>
```

I've substringed out the bit that I really care about:

```
this is &amp; ampersand
```

How do I now decode this snippet into (I'm not using yaws):

```
this is & ampersand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example

```
repl([],Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
repl([$&,$a,$m,$p,$;|T],Acc) -> repl(T,[$&|Acc]);
repl([H|T],Acc) -> repl(T,[H|Acc]).
```

checking

```
repl("this is &amp; ampersand",[]).
"this is & ampersand"
```

(update) If you need to replace all entities from cdata string, you could add bogus start tag around this string and parse it as xml.

Kind of:

```
  {{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,Lst,_,_,_},_} = 
     xmerl_scan:string("<root>"++YourStingHere++"</root>"),
  lists:foldl(fun ({_,_,_,_,X,text},Acc) -> Acc ++ X end, [],Lst).
```

checking:

```
 {{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,Lst,_,_,_},_} = 
         xmerl_scan:string("<root>"++"aaa V&amp;H &lt;- "++"</root>").
 lists:foldl(fun ({_,_,_,_,X,text},Acc) -> Acc ++ X end, [],Lst).

 "aaa V&H <- "
```

Comment: That's great for a single case, but what about the other HTML entities?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references  I was hoping there was a function written hidden in a library  already.

Comment: This update will work perfectly.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Including the built-in xmerl header file using `include_lib("xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl").` results in more readable and future-proof code. For example, `{_,_,_,_,X,text}` would become `Foo#xmlText.value`, and `{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,Lst,_,_,_}` could be replaced with `Foo#xmlElement.content`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of data do you have. If this is an ascii text, you could replace it with "&" sign like @Odobenus Rosmarus said, if this is an unicode, then you will do some additional amount of work. Look at [this](https://github.com/freeakk/ux) project or use standart `unicode` module.